# JSON.NET JArray IndexOf

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I have

```
var array = new JArray(new string[] { "one", "two", "three" });
```

But `array.IndexOf(new JValue("one"))` returns `-1`, which means that no such item found.

How to use `IndexOf` correctly to obtain index of element by value?

Comment: @GrantWinney edited

Comment: Used array of string just to populate the JArray. I needed exactly JArray version of IndexOf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1794). Also, here is [the linked stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47825490/jarray-removejtoken-does-not-delete/47826061#47826061) in the issue.