# Add JObject to another JObject in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have two `JObject`'s loaded from the following two JSON files:

```
{
  "data": {
    "organism": {
      "human": [
        {
          "firstName": "John",
          "lastName": "Doe"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "degrees": [
    {
      "type": "bachelor",
      "major": "Math"
    },
    {
      "type": "master",
      "major": "Computer Science"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to combine them into one `JObject` like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "organism": {
      "human": [
        {
          "firstName": "John",
          "lastName": "Doe",
          "degrees": [
            {
              "type": "bachelor",
              "major": "Math"
            },
            {
              "type": "master",
              "major": "Computer Science"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to add them as new field like this, but I am getting an error that i can't add `JObject` to another `JObject`:

```
jObject1["data"]["organism"]["human"][0]["lastName"].Parent.AddAfterSelf(jObject2)
```

I then tried to add it using `JProperty` but it just added a duplicate field which is not the format I need.

```
jObject1["data"]["organism"]["human"][0]["lastName"].Parent.AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("degrees",jobject2))
```

I am not sure how to proceed from this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as follows:

```
((JObject)jObject1["data"]["organism"]["human"][0]).Add(jObject2.Property("degrees"));
```

Notes:

- Casting the return of `jObject1["data"]["organism"]["human"][0]` to `JObject` ensures there really is a JSON object at that path.  Assuming the cast can be made, properties can be added easily.
- Your query adds an additional term `["lastName"]`, which essentially selects the [`JValue`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue_Value.htm) `"Doe"` corresponding to `"lastName": "Doe"`.  Not sure why you are doing that, so I removed it from my solution.
- [`JObject.Property`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Property.htm) returns the `JProperty` with the given name, or null if not found.  That `JProperty` can then be added to another `JObject` via its [`Add()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Add.htm) method.  Note that, in fact, a clone of the selected property is added, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47826061/3744182) to *[JArray.Remove(JToken) does not delete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47825490/3744182)* for why.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DxdSn9).