# JObject is losing reference

Tags: c#, json.net

I am having 2 scinarios to show the issue.

#### Scenario 1

```cs
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var arr = new JArray();
        arr.Add("apple");
        var obj = new JObject();
        obj["arr"] = arr;
        obj["arr"] = arr;       
        arr.Add("mango");
        
        foreach(var a in obj["arr"]){
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
        
                            
    }
}
```

Here `obj["array"]` should be referenceing the `arr`, i.e. initialized earlier. So the output should be

```
apple
mango
```

but the output was

```
apple
```

#### Scenario 2

```cs
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var arr = new JArray();
        arr.Add("apple");
        var obj = new JObject();
        obj["arr"] = arr;
        
        var obj2 = new JObject();
        obj2["arr"] = arr;      
        
        arr.Add("mango");
        
        foreach(var a in obj2["arr"]){
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly `obj2["arr"]` should be referencing the `arr`. but it is not.
So the expected output is

```
apple
mango
```

but the output is

```
apple
```

I am not that proficient in csharp. Please let me know if i am missing something here.

#### **Edit**

Adding another scenario as mentioned by @Wyck in comments.

#### Scenario 3

```cs
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var arr = new JArray();
        Console.WriteLine(arr.GetHashCode());
        arr.Add("apple");
        var obj = new JObject();
        obj["arr"] = arr;
        Console.WriteLine(obj["arr"].GetHashCode());
        obj["arr"] = arr;   
        Console.WriteLine(obj["arr"].GetHashCode());
        obj["arr"] = arr;   
        Console.WriteLine(obj["arr"].GetHashCode());
        
        arr.Add("mango");
        
        foreach(var a in obj["arr"]){
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
        
                            
    }
}
```

Repeating the assignment `obj["arr"] = arr` odd number of time gets back the original reference of `arr` but doing so even number of times doesn't.

The output of this will be

```
10465620
10465620
1190878
10465620
apple
mango
```

see the hash code is changed for even number assignment. for the odd number assignment it again became as before.

Comment: What did you hope to do by writing `obj["arr"] = arr;` twice?

Comment: @Wyck yeah, bit weird, but why it fails buzzles me, seems like a bug to me! See my comment on Krik's answer.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  For an explanation why see [nested json objects dont update / inherit using Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29260565/3744182) and [JArray.Remove(JToken) does not delete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47826061/3744182).

Comment: It may be "correct" but it is certainly "surprising"!

Comment: @Wyck - I believe LINQ-to-XML works similarly since the parent/child graph is doubly-connected there also.

Comment: @dbc - Scenario 2 is clear from your explanation. JToken can't have 2 parent. But how the behaviour shown by Wyck can be explained i.e. for odd number of times it works but not for even number of times... !

Comment: @ashutosh - I would need to see an [mcve], but **maybe** Json.NET doesn't check when you are trying to replace a token with itself (i.e. identical down to reference equality) so when you set `arr` the first time it gets cloned and de-parented, then when you set it the second time it gets set without cloning (because the parent was cleared).  A full example would clarify.

Comment: @dbc - i have updated my question to show that odd and even number assignment case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is totally based on @dbc's comment. This surprising behaviour is due to the way Json.net is implemented. The original answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29260565/12226178).

All `JToken` needs to have a `Parent` property and it can have only one `Parent`.

```cs
obj["arr"] = arr;
```

Here before setting `arr`, it is verified if `arr` has a `Parent` already. if `Parent` is `null`, `arr` will be assigned unmodified, otherwise `arr` will be cloned and the cloned `arr` will be assigned. This the reason behind the behaviour of Scenario 1 and Scenario 2.

```cs
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var arr = new JArray();
        
        arr.Add("apple");
        var obj = new JObject();
        obj["arr"] = arr;
        Console.WriteLine(arr.Parent == null ? "null" : arr.Parent.GetHashCode().ToString());
        obj["arr"] = arr;
        Console.WriteLine(arr.Parent == null ? "null" : arr.Parent.GetHashCode().ToString());
        obj["arr"] = arr;   
        Console.WriteLine(arr.Parent == null ? "null" : arr.Parent.GetHashCode().ToString());
        
        arr.Add("mango");
        
        foreach(var a in obj["arr"]){
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
        
                            
    }
}
```

The output of this code block will be

```
10566368
null
10566368
apple
mango
```

It can be seen, after even number of assignments the `Parent` of `arr` is set to `null`.

After the first assignment `arr.Parent` is set (`JProperty` containing the `Name` and its `Value`, which belongs `JOject`). During the second assignment, as `arr` already has a `Parent`, `arr` will be cloned and the cloned value will be set to the `obj["arr"]`. As a new `JToken` is set, `Parent` of the previous `JToken` will be set to `null` i.e. `arr.Parent` will become `null`.

Again on third assignment, `arr.Parent` is `null`. So it will be set like the first assignment.

for Scenario 2 `arr` already has a `Parent`, so during the 2nd assignment i.e. `obj2["arr"] = arr;`, `arr` will be cloned and set.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JProperty.cs#L329) for Newtonsoft.Json, you will find that when assigning an array to a property, it will create a copy of it:

```
public JProperty(string name, object? content)
{
    ...
    Value = IsMultiContent(content)
        ? new JArray(content)
        : CreateFromContent(content);
}
```

The relevent part of `JObject` is [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JObject.cs#L575).

You can easily test this in your code by getting the hash code (`.GetHashCode()`) of both `obj2["arr"]` and `arr` (both of type `JArray`) and observe that they will be different.

So in order to be able to add to the array, you need to access it via the instance of `JObject` once the property is assigned, or you can re-assign the array to the property whenever you add an element.

Comment: Thought so, but there is something off. If you assign it once, it works by referencing the original array (not through JObject), however, if you assign it twich (for whatever reason you are doing that), it seems to create a copy.

However, if you assign something else like arr2, and then assign it again, it works!


**works**: `obj["arr"] = arr; obj["arr"] = arr2; obj["arr"] = arr;`
**works:** `obj["arr"] = arr;`
**doesn't work!**: `obj["arr"] = arr; obj["arr"] = arr;`

Comment: More strangely if you do `obj["arr"] = arr` an **odd** number of times it works.  If you do it an **even** number of times, you get some other object.  (try doing it 3, 4, 5, or 6 times!)

Comment: @Ghasanغسان - your observation is correct.  A `JToken` can have only one parent, so cloning is only required when trying to add a token that already has a parent.