# Clone a JsonNode and attach it to another one in .NET 6

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-6.0, system.text.json

I'm using `System.Text.Json.Nodes` in .NET 6.0 and what I'm trying to do is simple: Copy a JsonNode from one and attach the node to another JsonNode.
The following is my code.

```cs
public static string concQuest(string input, string allQuest, string questId) {
    JsonNode inputNode = JsonNode.Parse(input)!;
    JsonNode allQuestNode = JsonNode.Parse(allQuest)!;
    JsonNode quest = allQuestNode.AsArray().First(quest => 
        quest!["id"]!.GetValue<string>() == questId) ?? throw new KeyNotFoundException("No matching questId found.");
    inputNode["quest"] = quest;  // Exception occured
    return inputNode.ToJsonString(options);
}
```

But when I try to run it, I got a `System.InvalidOperationException` said `"The node already has a parent."`

I've tried edit

```
inputNode["quest"] = quest;
```

to

```
inputNode["quest"] = quest.Root; // quest.Root is also a JsonNode
```

Then the code runs well but it returns all nodes instead of the one I specified which is not the result I want. Also since the code works fine, I think it is feasible to set a JsonNode to another one directly.
According to the exception message, it seems if I want to add a JsonNode to another one, I must unattach it from its parent first, but how can I do this?

Note that my JSON file is quite big (more than 6MB), so I want to ensure there are no performance issues with my solution.

Comment: What does your JSON look like?  Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: _"I want to ensure there are no performance issues with my solution."_ - if you want to be sure that there are no issues you need to take some implementation at test it's performance against real data. Actually in quite a lot of cases "good enough" is a way to go without need for premature optimisation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prior to .NET 8, [`JsonNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode?view=net-6.0) has no `Clone()` method, so the easiest way to copy it is probably to invoke the serializer's [`JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TValue>(JsonNode, JsonSerializerOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserialize?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-jsonserializer-deserialize-1(system-text-json-nodes-jsonnode-system-text-json-jsonserializeroptions)) extension method to deserialize your node directly into another node.  First, introduce the following extension methods to copy or move a node:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static TNode? CopyNode<TNode>(this TNode? node) where TNode : JsonNode => node?.Deserialize<TNode>();

    public static JsonNode? MoveNode(this JsonArray array, int id, JsonObject newParent, string name)
    {
        var node = array[id];
        array.RemoveAt(id); 
        return newParent[name] = node;
    }

    public static JsonNode? MoveNode(this JsonObject parent, string oldName, JsonObject newParent, string name)
    {
        parent.Remove(oldName, out var node);
        return newParent[name] = node;
    }

    public static TNode ThrowOnNull<TNode>(this TNode? value) where TNode : JsonNode => value ?? throw new JsonException("Null JSON value");
}
```

Now your code may be written as follows:

```
public static string concQuest(string input, string allQuest, string questId) 
{
    var inputObject = JsonNode.Parse(input).ThrowOnNull().AsObject();
    var allQuestArray = JsonNode.Parse(allQuest).ThrowOnNull().AsArray();
    concQuest(inputObject, allQuestArray, questId);
    return inputObject.ToJsonString();
}       

public static JsonNode? concQuest(JsonObject inputObject, JsonArray allQuestArray, string questId) 
{
    // Enumerable.First() will throw an InvalidOperationException if no element is found satisfying the predicate.
    var node = allQuestArray.First(quest => quest!["id"]!.GetValue<string>() == questId);
    return inputObject["quest"] = node.CopyNode();
}
```

**Update for .NET 8:**  .NET 8 introduces [`JsonNode.DeepClone()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode.deepclone) so in .NET 8 and later `JsonExtensions.CopyNode()` may be eliminated and the second `concQuest()` method written as follows:

```
public static JsonNode? concQuest(JsonObject inputObject, JsonArray allQuestArray, string questId) 
{
    // Enumerable.First() will throw an InvalidOperationException if no element is found satisfying the predicate.
    var node = allQuestArray.First(quest => quest!["id"]!.GetValue<string>() == questId);
    return inputObject["quest"] = node?.DeepClone();
}
```

Alternatively, if you aren't going to keep your array of quests around, you could just move the node from the array to the target like so:

```
public static string concQuest(string input, string allQuest, string questId) 
{
    var inputObject = JsonNode.Parse(input).ThrowOnNull().AsObject();
    var allQuestArray = JsonNode.Parse(allQuest).ThrowOnNull().AsArray();
    concQuest(inputObject, allQuestArray, questId);
    return inputObject.ToJsonString();
}       

public static JsonNode? concQuest(JsonObject inputObject, JsonArray allQuestArray, string questId) 
{
    // Enumerable.First() will throw an InvalidOperationException if no element is found satisfying the predicate.
    var (_, index) = allQuestArray.Select((quest, index) => (quest, index)).First(p => p.quest!["id"]!.GetValue<string>() == questId);
    return allQuestArray.MoveNode(index, inputObject, "quest");
}
```

Also, you wrote

> since my json file is quite big (more than 6MB), I was worried there might be some performance issues.

In that case I would avoid loading the JSON files into the `input` and `allQuest` strings because strings larger than 85,000 bytes go on the [large object heap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8953503/3744182) which can cause subsequent performance degradation.  Instead, deserialize directly from the relevant files into `JsonNode` arrays and objects like so:

```
var questId = "2"; // Or whatever

JsonArray allQuest;
using (var stream = new FileStream(allQuestFileName, new FileStreamOptions { Mode = FileMode.Open, Access = FileAccess.Read }))
    allQuest = JsonNode.Parse(stream).ThrowOnNull().AsArray();

JsonObject input;
using (var stream = new FileStream(inputFileName, new FileStreamOptions { Mode = FileMode.Open, Access = FileAccess.Read }))
    input = JsonNode.Parse(stream).ThrowOnNull().AsObject();

JsonExtensions.concQuest(input, allQuest, questId);

using (var stream = new FileStream(inputFileName, new FileStreamOptions { Mode = FileMode.Create, Access = FileAccess.Write }))
using (var writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(stream, new JsonWriterOptions { Indented = true }))
    input.WriteTo(writer);
```

Or, if your app is asynchronous, you can do:

```
JsonArray allQuest;
await using (var stream = new FileStream(allQuestFileName, new FileStreamOptions { Mode = FileMode.Open, Access = FileAccess.Read, Options = FileOptions.Asynchronous }))
    allQuest = (await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<JsonArray>(stream)).ThrowOnNull();

JsonObject input;
await using (var stream = new FileStream(inputFileName, new FileStreamOptions { Mode = FileMode.Open, Access = FileAccess.Read, Options = FileOptions.Asynchronous }))
    input = (await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<JsonObject>(stream)).ThrowOnNull();

JsonExtensions.concQuest(input, allQuest, questId);

await using (var stream = new FileStream(inputFileName, new FileStreamOptions { Mode = FileMode.Create, Access = FileAccess.Write, Options = FileOptions.Asynchronous }))
    await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(stream, input, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
```

Notes:

- Microsoft's documentation [explicitly recommends against serializing from and to strings instead of UTF-8 byte sequences for performance reasons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#serialize-to-utf-8) which is another reason not to load your large JSON files into temporary string buffers.

Demo fiddles:

- For copying the node in .NET 6, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/LX3AqH
- For copying the node in .NET 8, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/B84Ba1.
- For moving the node, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/cI8DuB.
- For async reading and writing, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/VjKstQ

Comment: Many thanks for your answers and suggestions, I think this is probably the best solution for now. There is one more thing I am curious about, why can't we copy a JsonNode to another one directly if it already has a parent? What's the problem if we do so?

Comment: @Vibbit - I don't know why MSFT designed their API that way.  With Json.NET, when you assign a node with a parent to another node, the node is automatically cloned, see [nested json objects dont update / inherit using Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29260565/3744182).  Maybe the API designers at MSFT didn't like that so they decided to throw an exception instead as the simplest thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest option would be to convert json node into string and parse it again (though possibly not the most performant one):

```
var destination = @"{}";
var source = "[{\"id\": 1, \"name\":\"some quest\"},{}]";
var sourceJson = JsonNode.Parse(source);
var destinationJson = JsonNode.Parse(destination);
var quest = sourceJson.AsArray().First();
destinationJson["quest"] = JsonNode.Parse(quest.ToJsonString());
Console.WriteLine(destinationJson.ToJsonString(new() { WriteIndented = true }));
```

Will print:

```
{
  "quest": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "some quest"
  }
}
```

**UPD**

Another trick is to deserialize the `JsonNode` to `JsonNode`:

```
...
var quest = sourceJson.AsArray().First();    
var clone = quest.Deserialize<JsonNode>();
clone["name"] = "New name"; 
destinationJson["quest"] = clone;
Console.WriteLine(quest["name"]);
Console.WriteLine(destinationJson.ToJsonString(new() { WriteIndented = true }));
```

Prints:

```json
some quest
{
  "quest": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "New name"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I also considered this solution. However since my json file is quite big (more than 6MB), I was worried there might be some performance issues.

Comment: @Vibbit 6 mb is size of one quest?

Answer (score 1):

The official API for creating a `JsonNode` from a .Net object (including another `JsonNode`) appears to be the [JsonSerializer.SerializeToNode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serializetonode) method which is available in .Net 6+. Digging [under the covers](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonSerializer.Write.Node.cs#L151C4-L151C4), this method simply writes the .Net object to a memory buffer and then deserializes it. As such, there still might be performance degradation with cloning large structures.

If the `allQuest` JSON is quite large, you can avoid loading the whole content into memory as parsed JSON using the [JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserializeasyncenumerable) method. This technique is [described elsewhere](https://medium.com/geekculture/parsing-huge-json-files-using-streams-in-net-d620dace47e2) (requires log-in).

Combining these methods, the code could become.

```cs
public static string concQuest(string input, Stream allQuest, string questId) {
    JsonNode inputNode = JsonNode.Parse(input)!;
    JsonNode quest = JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable<JsonNode>(allQuest)
        .ToBlockingEnumerable()
        .First(quest => quest!["id"]!.GetValue<string>() == questId) 
            ?? throw new KeyNotFoundException("No matching questId found.");
    inputNode["quest"] = JsonSerializer.SerializeToNode(quest);
    return inputNode.ToJsonString(options);
}
```