# How to add a new property to JsonElement using System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

Let's say I have Dictionary<string, object> metas. The object could be JsonElement (System.Text.Json)

And I need iterate each element if the object is an array of elements, and add new property to each element.

I can iterate elements like this:

```
var metaValue = metas["key-1"];

if (metaValue is JsonElement elementValue && elementValue.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Array)
 {
    // Iterate over the elements in the array
    foreach (var element in elementValue.EnumerateArray())
    {
        // add new property to element
        // like element["newproperty"] = "test value"
    }
 }
```

My question is, how to add new property to JsonElement?

Comment: How was your `Dictionary<string, object> metas` constructed?  Was it constructed by deserializing JSON to a `Dictionary<string, object>` e.g. as follows: `var metas = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json)`?

Comment: Also, what version of .NET are you using?  .NET 6, later, or earlier?

Comment: I am using .net 6. the dictionary<string, object> is a property of a class MyType, which deserialized from json usine JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyType>(..)

Comment: Then, as suggested in my answer. I would deserialize with the option `JsonSerializerOptions.UnknownTypeHandling = JsonUnknownTypeHandling.JsonNode`.  That way your dictionary values will be mutable `JsonNode` objects rather than immutable `JsonElement` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify [`JsonElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement), it is completely immutable.  Instead, you must deserialize it to some mutable type such as [`JsonNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode), modify the mutable type, then re-serialize back to `JsonElement`.  The following method does that:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonNode TryAddPropertyToArrayElements<TProperty>(this JsonNode node, string name, TProperty value)
    {
        if (node is JsonArray array)
            foreach (var obj in array.OfType<JsonObject>())
                obj[name] = JsonSerializer.SerializeToNode(value);
        return node;
    }

    public static JsonElement TryAddPropertyToArrayElements<TProperty>(this JsonElement element, string name, TProperty value) =>
        element.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Array
        ? JsonSerializer.SerializeToElement(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonNode>(element)!.TryAddPropertyToArrayElements(name, value))
        : element;

    public static object? TryAddPropertyToArrayElements<TProperty>(this object? obj, string name, TProperty value) =>
        obj switch
        {
            JsonElement e => e.TryAddPropertyToArrayElements(name, value),
            JsonNode n => n.TryAddPropertyToArrayElements(name, value),
            null => null, // JSON values that are null are deserialized to the c# null value, not some element or node of type null
            _ => throw new ArgumentException("Unexpected type ${obj}"),
        };
}
```

Then you would use it as follows:

```
metas["key-1"] = metas["key-1"]?
    .TryAddPropertyToArrayElements("newproperty", "test value");
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3ToyPo).

Obviously all this serialization is somewhat inefficient.  To avoid the extra serialization, assuming you generated your dictionary via deserialization, you could deserialize with [`JsonSerializerOptions.UnknownTypeHandling = JsonUnknownTypeHandling.JsonNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonunknowntypehandling?view=net-7.0).  This setting forces types declared as `object` to be deserialized to `JsonNode` rather than `JsonElement`:

```
var inputOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    UnknownTypeHandling = JsonUnknownTypeHandling.JsonNode,
};
var metas = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object?>>(json, inputOptions)!;
```

If you do you will be able to mutate its values directly using the method `JsonExtensions.TryAddPropertyToArrayElements<TProperty>(this JsonNode node, string name, TProperty value)` included above.

Notes:

- `JsonNode` and `JsonSerializer.SerializeToElement()` were introduced in .NET 6 so if you are using an earlier version you will need to use a different approach.

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NB6xJp).

Comment: Thanks dbc! Your answer worked perfectly! Just more question, in some case I just want to assign the new added property the value of an existing property with this code jsonObject["newproperty"] = JsonObject["existingProperty"]; // jsonObject is item of JsonArray which deserialized with your approach. Then I got this error : System.InvalidOperationException: 'The node already has a parent. What does this mean?

Comment: @Youxu - you're welcome.  The *`The node already has a parent`* error happens because `JsonNode` objects form doubly-connected graphs: parents know their children and children know their parents.  So when you assign a child that already has a parent to a different parent, the library would need to do something such as remove it from the old parent, or clone it.  This isn't implemented, hence the error.  See [Clone a JsonNode and attach it to another one in .NET 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71570877/3744182).

Comment: Thanks @dbc! marked the answer as answered.