# JsonNode - The node already has a parent

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json

I'm using `.NET 6` and `System.Text.Json`. What I'm trying to do is iterate over http calls, deserialize as a json node, pick a property out of the node which is an array, perform an operation on each node then add them to a `JsonArray`. My code looks something like this:

```
JsonArray allData = new();
...
var httpResponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync("my url");
var responseObject = httpResponse.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<JsonNode>();
var responseData = JsonNode.Parse(responseObject ["myKey"].ToString()).AsArray();
foreach(var obj in responseData)
{
  // do some operations
}
allData.AddRange(responseData);
```

I call the above in a loop so there will be multiple iterations of this to build up the `allData` array.
The problem is when I do `allData.AddRange(responseData);` I am getting an exception with the message :

> The node already has a parent

In this case it is referring to the JsonObjects in the `responseData`, they each have a readonly Parent that points to the `responseData` array. I've done a bunch of Googling around this but have come up with nothing useful. How would I accomplish this? I can't seem to find a way to clear the parent from the objects in my `JsonArray`, and I can't seem to find a way to re-assign the parent either. Any advice on how to proceed here would be appreciated, I'm stumped right now. Thanks much!

Comment: Related or duplicate: [Clone a JsonNode and attach it to another one in .NET 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71570877/3744182).  Does that question answer your question sufficiently to consider it a duplicate?